# How to resume reading after EOF in named pipe

Tags: go, named-pipes

I'm writing a program which opens a named pipe for reading, and then processes any lines written to this pipe:

```
err = syscall.Mkfifo("/tmp/myfifo", 0666)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

pipe, err := os.OpenFile("/tmp/myfifo", os.O_RDONLY, os.ModeNamedPipe)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

reader := bufio.NewReader(pipe)
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)

for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    process(line)
}
```

This works fine as long as the writing process does not restart or for other reasons send an EOF. When this happens, the loop terminates (as expected from the specifications of `Scanner`).

However, I want to keep the pipe open to accept further writes. I *could* just reinitialize the scanner of course, but I believe this would create a race condition where the scanner might not be ready while a new process has begun writing to the pipe.

Are there any other options? Do I need to work directly with the `File` type instead?

Comment: You need a new scanner, where would there be a race?

Comment: @JimB My worry would be the case where the writer disconnects, I get an EOF and fall out of the loop to recreate the scanner. Before this has finished, the writer has restarted and resumed writing to the pipe. Possibly this would just lead to the writes being buffered though? I guess it depends if I need to also close the file handle.

Answer (score 0):

From the [bufio GoDoc](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Scan):

> Scan ... returns false when the scan stops, either by reaching the end of the input or an error.

So you could possibly leave the file open and read until EOF, then trigger `scanner.Scan()` again when the file has changed or at a regular interval (i.e. make a goroutine), and make sure the `pipe` variable doesn't go out of scope so you can reference it again.

If I understand your concern about a race condition correctly, this wouldn't be an issue (unless write and read operations must be synchronized) but when the scanner is re-initialized it will end up back at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Also from the docs: `Scanning stops unrecoverably at EOF` -- you can't just call Scan again.